# How to push a prop passed from a parent component to an array in the child component?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have 3 components. One parent component and two child components. The two child components are siblings.

Parent Component

```js
 <template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-content">

        <Modal :popupTitle="popupTitle" @addLocation="addLocation($event)"/>
        
        <BinInfo :newBinLocation="newBinLocation"/>

        <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Add new bin</button>
    </div>
  </div>  
 </template>

<script>


export default {
    data(){
      return{
        popupTitle:"Add New Bin Location",
        newBinLocation: '',
      }
   },
   methods:{
     addLocation(newBinLocation){
       this.newBinLocation = newBinLocation
     }
   },
  components:{
      Navigation,
      TopBtns,
      BinInfo,
  }
}
</script>
```

In one child, which is the listing component, I am showing a listing from an array

Listing Component

```js
<template>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <h2>Bins - Location</h2>
    <h5 v-if="bins.length==0">There are no bin locations added</h5>
    <table class="table table-striped" v-if="bins.length > 0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Location</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-end">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(bin, index) in bins" :key="index">
            <th scope="row">{{index + 1}}</th>
            <td><input ref="inputField" type="text" :value="bin.binlocation" :disabled="bin.disabled" @change="editedLocation=$event.target.value"></td>
            <td class="text-end">
            <div class="action-btn">
                <button @click="btnEdit(index)"><fa icon="edit" /> Edit</button>
                <button @click="btnUpdate(index)"><fa icon="edit" /> Update</button>
                <button @click="btnDelete(index)"><fa icon="trash" /> Delete</button>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="btn-area">
        <router-link to="/bins">View More</router-link>
    </div>
</div>
{{newBinLocation}}

</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            bins:[
                {
                    binlocation: '11 Garden Block, New City',
                    disabled: true
                },
                {
                    binlocation: 'Ali Towers, Lahore',
                    disabled: true
                },
                {
                    binlocation: 'The Mall Road',
                    disabled: true
                }
            ],
            editedLocation: null,
        }
    },
    props:['newBinLocation'],
    methods:{
        btnDelete(index){
           this.bins.splice(index, 1)
        },
        btnEdit(index){
         this.bins[index].disabled = !this.bins[index].disabled;
         this.editedLocation = this.bins[index].binlocation
         /*if(this.bins[index].disabled === false){
             console.log(this.$refs.inputField)
         }*/
        },
        btnUpdate(index){
           this.bins[index].binlocation = this.editedLocation
           this.bins[index].disabled = !this.bins[index].disabled
           console.log(this.bins[index].binlocation)
        },
        btnAdd(){
            let newLocation = {
                binlocation: this.newBinLocation,
                disabled: true
            }
            this.bins.push(newLocation)
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.table-responsive{
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
h2{margin:0 0 15px;}
.action-btn button{
    border:0;
    background:#003594;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:3px 15px;
}
.action-btn button:hover{
    background:#3490dc
}
input{
    background-color:none;
    border:0;
    color:#000;
}
</style>
```

and in the second child component, I have created a modal which I am using to add a new list.

Modal Component

```js
<template>
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{popupTitle}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><input type="text" v-model="addBinLocation"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button @click="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Location</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['popupTitle'],
    data(){
      return{
        addBinLocation: ''
      }
    },
    methods:{
      btnAdd(){
        this.$emit('addLocation', this.addBinLocation)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I am able to add and receive the values but how can I add the new prop into the existing array so that it is added in the list.

Comment: What do you mean by `how can I add the new prop into the existing array so that it is added in the list.`? Add a prop to an array?

Comment: We miss some context. Can you share the code with the array ?

Comment: Could you post the template as well? Because normally you would listen in the parent component to the emitted event and then update the array in the parent component

Comment: Your parent component needs to have an internal array, where you `push` the new item into and then use this as a prop on the listing component which can then iterate over the items in this array.

Comment: @null, yes I need to add the prop to an array. I am passing the prop from the parent to the child, this prop has to be added in the array which is the in list child component

Comment: @Thomas - so you are saying that I should have an array in the parent component also and the new added list should be pushed into that internal array and this will be used as a prop on the listing component. But what about the array with the existing data in the child component? Will that also be displayed with the new array which is passed as prop?

Comment: This array with the existing data should only be in the parent and this is the array you push new items in. So the child only has this one array as a prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to add the `newBinLocation` with a computed property in the `Listing Component`, but it isn’t the cleanest way to do this.

You made a architecture error by declaring the `bins` array in the `Listing Component`. The parent component should be the one aware of the data. the `Listing Component` is only here to print a list.

You should pass the array from the `Parent Component` as a props. This way the `Listing Component` will be easily reusable.

Once you’ve done that it’s easy to add an new item to the array.

Here is an example

**Parent component**

```js
 <template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-content">

        <Modal :popupTitle="popupTitle" @addLocation="addLocation($event)"/>
        
        <BinInfo :bins="bins"/> <-- You need to pass the array instead of newBinLocation -->

        <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Add new bin</button>
    </div>
  </div>  
 </template>

<script>


export default {
    data() {
      return {
        popupTitle:"Add New Bin Location",
        bins:[
                {
                    binlocation: '11 Garden Block, New City',
                    disabled: true
                },
                {
                    binlocation: 'Ali Towers, Lahore',
                    disabled: true
                },
                {
                    binlocation: 'The Mall Road',
                    disabled: true
                }
          ],
      }
   },
   methods:{
     addLocation(newBinLocation){
       this.bins.push(newBinLocation) // You just have to push the new value
     }
   },
  components:{
      Navigation,
      TopBtns,
      BinInfo,
  }
}
</script>
```